# Anonymous Access to custom webservices (403 error)

Tags: web-services, 2007

I am trying to add some ajax functionality to a public facing site and have added a custom web service both into the layouts fodler and also into _vti_bin.

I can browse to the asmx file OK however am getting a 403 error when trying to call the service via Ajax.

Anonymous browsing is on for the site.

Am I missing something out to get it to work anonymously

On a side note I found when I browse to the asmx file in the layout folder the 'Invoke' button is available however when I browse to the asmx file in the _vti_bin folder it is not visible. Not sure if this is related

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

I had not configured the web.config in the _vti_bin folder correctly

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid messing with _layouts or _vti_bin. Use the webapplication folder to deploy custom services unless its common and use at the enterprise level.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ViewFormPagesLockDown feature enabled on your site? (note: It should be for any internet facing sites and it is enabled by default on publishing sites) This feature takes away the UseRemoteAPIs and ViewFormPages permissions from anonymous users. I ran into issues with this that are documented [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/infopath-forms-not-working-when-viewformpageslockdown-enabled).