# InfoPath 2010 as Internet facing form

Tags: infopath, publishing-site, publishing-page

I have seen a lot of examples of infoPath forms being built and deployed to a team site or some other internal structure but I haven't seen any examples of forms being deployed to anonymous users as an internet facing form on a publishing site

Is there anything that can be done on a teamsite for example that can't be done on a external facing internet site?

Or is it still a matter of creating a form and adding it to a web part for all to see online?

Answer (score 1):

SPR,

You can use InfoPath forms with Public Facing SharePoint websites.. But few problems come with Anonymous Users, since if you want the public to submit forms for you, you will definitely like to have a Approval Workflow or something... But Anonymous Users cannot fire a Workflow! Also, since forms are submitted in a library and you open anonymous access on the form library... Anything can be submitted to the library which can be a security hole...

See below threads which will help you make your decision:
[Anonymous Access users can't submit InfoPath 2010 form to Form Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33916/anonymous-access-users-cant-submit-infopath-2010-form-to-form-library)
[Public Facing Site on SharePoint 2010: Web Forms](http://blog.knowledgelake.com/2010/08/public-facing-website-on-sharepoint-2010-%E2%80%93-part-2-web-forms/)

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response, that is indeed helpful. I am new to SharePoint and although I can test things on an internal teamsite, I am not sure how to test these things on a public facing website. If I just want the form to send an email with all the form details to an "Enquiries mailbox" does that get rid of the issue of users having to fire a workflow.

Comment: @SPR You can achieve things via coding or just sending an email then manual process to start workflow or approve/reject items maybe... Depends on your requirement!